# How to replace fragment run time

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-widget

I want to add and replace Frame layout with fragment on fragment-1 and fragment-2 on item click of Grid and List item.

I had created main.xml class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.fragment.Fragment1" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.fragment.Fragment2" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

Here is my fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/Grid1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

and here is my row_fragment1_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_view"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and fragment_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_fragment3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is 3rd Fragment" />
```

and here is my Main.xml

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

and here is Fragment1.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener
{
    Activity myActivity;
    GridView mGridView; 
    private String ListItem[] = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5","Item 6","Item 7"};
    private int imgID[] = {R.drawable.admin_access_rule,
            R.drawable.admin_backup,R.drawable.admin_browsesite,
            R.drawable.admin_comment_post,R.drawable.admin_content,
            R.drawable.admin_content_type,R.drawable.admin_logout,};

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.myActivity = activity;
        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "On Attach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1,container, false);
        mGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.Grid1);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Activity Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
        mGridView.setAdapter(new GridBaseAdapter(myActivity));
        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private class GridBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
        public GridBaseAdapter(Context mContext) 
        {
            mContext = myActivity;
            mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
    {
        return ListItem.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return ListItem.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if(convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_fragment_list, null);
        }

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        mImageView.setImageResource(imgID[position]);

        TextView tvUserEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tvUserEmail.setText("Sub " +ListItem[position]);            

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    TextView txt3 = (TextView)myActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment3);
    txt3.setText("1st Fragment's : " + position +" Item Clicked");
}
}
```

My Fragment2.class

```
public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment
{
    Activity myActivity;
    private String ListItem[] = {"Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5","Item 6","Item 6","Item 7"};

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.myActivity = activity;
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "On Attach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     /** Creating an array adapter to store the list of countries **/
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ListItem);
    /** Setting the list adapter for the ListFragment */
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Activity Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), position +" Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    TextView txt3 = (TextView)myActivity.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment3);
    txt3.setText("2nd Fragment's : " + position +" Item Clicked");
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
}
```

And Last my Fragment3.class

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment
{
Activity myActivity;
TextView txt_view;  
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.myActivity = activity;
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "On Attach", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Create View", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3,container, false);
    txt_view = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment3);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Toast.makeText(myActivity.getApplicationContext(), "On Activity Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you expect someone to go through all that code when you haven't even stated whats going wrong in the question?

Comment: If you don't encourage new comers than don't discourage us.

Comment: I can't believe how you can get 2 upvotes on this. My comment was just because the question could have been much more clear if you would have done some research about your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make fragments expose interface that your activity can attach itself to. The event should occur when desired (e.g. list item is clicked). Then, activity should place instance of the fragment where it should be, for example:

```
// fragment is an instance of the fragment you want to show
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment3, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```